Understanding Munkres Topology Lemma 13.2
Lemma 13.2 from the book:

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a
collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$
and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such
that $x\in C\subset U$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for the topology
of $X$.

Munkres asserts that $X$ is in $\mathcal{C}$. I wanted to prove this by first letting $x$ in $X$. However, I don't know how to proceed from here. How do I prove that there exists $C\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C$ and $C\subset X$?
EDIT: Here is the relevant part of the proof from the book, verbatim. Please let me know if I'm misinterpreting something.

We must show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. The first condition for a basis is easy: Given $x\in X$, since $X$ is itself an open set, there is by hypothesis an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset X$.

EDIT 2: I found out what I was doing wrong. I realized what he meant was


$\mathcal{C}=\{U\in\mathcal{T}\}$
$\forall U\in\mathcal{T}, \forall x\in U, \exists C\in\mathcal{C}, x\in C, C\subset U$


But I interpreted it as

$\mathcal{C}=\{U\in\mathcal{T}\mid \forall x\in U, \exists C\in \mathcal{C}, x\in C, C\subset U\}$


You should start by asking "What does it mean for a collection to be a basis for a topology? What exactly would I need to show?"

Do you mean that $X$ is generated by $\mathcal{C}$? And the claim you mention afterwards should follow directly from the definition of $\mathcal{C}$. Just pick $U=X$.

I highly doubt the book says $X\in\mathcal C$, and if it does it's false.

I am not trying to prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. I just want to understand why $X$ is in $\mathcal{C}$. And to prove this I must show that there exists an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C$ and $C\subset X$. This doesn't follow directly in my head, could you explain this in more detail please?

@yegeunyang if that's really is the case then it's not necessarily true. Consider $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal C$ the open balls or radii less than $1$. They satisfy that property (and they're indeed a basis) but they don't contain $\mathbb R$

The following excerpt is from Munkres' topology second edition

It never claims that $X\in\mathcal C$. As I noted in the comments this need not be true, for instance, in any metric space the collection of balls of radius less than $1$ satisfies said condition (so it is a basis), in particular, if the diameter of your space is at least $1$ then this collection does not contain the metric space itself. Therefore such a claim cannot be universally true. I think your confusion probably comes from the second line of the proof, where he shows that the first condition for being a basis is satisfied, just claiming that $X$ is an open set, not an element of the base.

I assume your definition of basis is the Munkres' definition which is:
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of open sets of $X$. $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for topological space $X$ if

For every $x\in X$, there is some $B\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in B$,
If $x\in B_1 \cap B_2$ for some $B_1,B_2\in \mathcal{C}$, there is some $B_3\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

Now we can show if $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for every open set $U\subseteq X$ and every $x\in U$, there is $C\in \mathcal{C}$ with $x\in C\subseteq U$, then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for X.
To prove $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis, we have to show $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies 1 and 2 from our definition.

Given $x\in X$, recall that $X$ is an open subset of $X$. So we will take $U=X$ and by our assumption, there is $C\in\mathcal{C}$ with $x\in C\subseteq X$.

Thus we have shown  1. That is we have shown for every $x\in X$ there is $C\in \mathcal{C}$ with $x\in C\subseteq X$.
2)Let $x\in C_1\cap C_2$ for some $C_1,C_2\in \mathcal{C}$. Since both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are basis elements, they are open subsets of $X$. Finite intersection of open sets are open, and so $C_1\cap C_2$ is an open subset of X. Thus we will take $U=C_1\cap C_2$ and use our assumption to get $C\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C \subseteq U$.
Thus we have shown  2. That is we have shown for every $x\in C_1 \cap C_2$ for some $C_1,C_2\in \mathcal{C}$, there is some $C\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subseteq C_1\cap C_2$.
Hence $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies 1 and 2. So it is a basis for $X$

I know that if $X$ is in $\mathcal{C}$, then by the assumption, there exists $C\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C$ and $C\subset X$. However, how do I show that $X$ is in $\mathcal{C}$?

@yegeunyang You do not need $X \in \mathcal{C}$. Read the hypothesis in the lemma again. It says that "for each open set $U$ of $X$ there exists $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$" and $X$ is open in itself (convince yourself why) hence there should exists an open set $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$ (by hypothesis) such that $x \in C \subset X$.
